# Render results on #show without storing data in ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imgur

I'm learning RoR by building my first app (yay!). I gotta a question thought as rails guides do not cover this topic:

**How to render unique results on #show to a user without storing any data in a model?**

Steps I want to take:

1. Create a basic *index* view with a form_tag that will allow user to submit a link (string) and click submit button
2. Write Service Objects that will allow me to parse that link and create a response I want user to see
3. I want to write a #show method in a separate controller that will allow me to display all the data. (I also want to parse my params[:link] in that method using Service Objects.
4. I want to finally display this data in a table in #show view (probably I need to create a unique #show/[:id] for each user?

Here's what my app looks like at the moment (more or less):

**Static Controller** (just to render index.html.erb with a form)

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

**Static Index view** (yup, parsing imgur link here)

```
<h1>Hello Rails!</h1>

<%= form_tag("/images", method: "post") do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag(:imgur_link) %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag(:imgur) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= submit_tag("Get my cards") %>
  </p>
    <% end %>
```

**Images Controller (where all the magic SHOULD happen)**

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @collection = params[:imgur_link]
    @service1 = service1.new(*args).call
    @service2 = service2.new(*args).call
    ...
  end
end
```

**Images Show view**

Empty as I'm stuck with the Images controller at the moment.

Any help would be more than appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If you refer to it as `imgur_link`, than in `text_field_tag` you should also call it `imgur_link`

Comment: Fair point. Fixing atm ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason you should put something into storage just in order to display it. If you get to a point when you have the results in your controller, you could just pass them to view in some `@variable`

As I see, you have set up the form for step 1. If you also have `routes.rb` call 'images#show' for `POST /images`, then you will have `params[:imgur_link]` available in your show action. This should do:

```
# config/routes.rb
YourApplication.routes.draw do 
  # ...
  post '/images' => 'images#show'
end
```

Now you have to somehow process that link. Since I don't know what your results should be, I'm going to assume that you have two classes, `Service1` and `Service2`, both of which accept an URL and return collection of results, and both collections hold the elements of the same class. Then you can leave only unique results for your `show` view, like this:

```
# app/controllers/images_controller.rb
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    link = params[:imgur_link]
    results1 = Service1.new(link).results
    results2 = Service2.new(link).results

    @results = (results1 + results2).uniq
  end
end
```

Then you can do something with `@results` in your `show` view. E.g.

```
# app/views/images/show.html.erb
<% @results.each do |result| %>
  <%= result.inspect %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yup. Exactly that. I managed to pass the variable properly  and make the view itself work. Now I'm fixing my Service Objects as apparently I failed to write them correctly. I'm much closer though. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: Done. Sorry for the delay.